# Element-wise sum of nested lists

Tags: python, sum, nested-lists, elementwise-operations, strerror

I have a nested list called list_6:

[[-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1],...]]

each element of the list contains integers from -1,1, and the elements are of unequal length, there are 20 elements in the list

I would like to create a new list called list_7 that looks like:

[[13],[4],[5],...]], so that each element in the nested list is summed, and the result is printed. I tried using iter.zip_longest:

[sum(i) for i in itertools.zip_longest(*list_6, fillvalue=0)]

but am getting an error function:

'str' object is not callable

Comment: How are you getting an `'str' object is not callable` error? It is not possible with just the code you posted. Please update your question with a reproducible code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using list comprehension https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension

`list_7 = [sum(inner_list) for inner_list in list_6]`

Within the brackets (`[]`) you are iterating over each item in list_6.
Since each item in list_6 is itself a list (`inner_list`) we can call python's `sum` function on the list to get the sum of the values within `inner_list` https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp.

I see now that you were looking for the sums to be lists themselves (`[[13],[4],[5],...]],`) in which case you would want to do:

`list_7 = [[sum(inner_list)] for inner_list in list_6]`

Putting brackets around `sum(inner_list)` creates a new list whose only entry is the sum of the inner_list.

Comment: I was about to give the same because `list comprehension` is truly a good way